# Run GitHub Action when pushing commit but not on tag

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

In my GitHub repo, I have three different GitHub Actions ([see here](https://github.com/mu88/ScreenshotCreator/tree/main/.github/workflows)):

- `CI.yml`
- `Mutation Testing.yml`
- `Release.yml`

The CI pipeline gets triggered on every commit:

```yaml
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
```

The Release pipeline gets triggered whenever a new tag gets pushed:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

But when pushing a new tag for a release, the CI pipeline also gets triggered and I want to avoid this. So I tried the following syntax for `CI.yml` (according to [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-excluding-branches-and-tags)):

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags-ignore:        
      - '*'
  pull_request:
```

But now the CI pipeline is not triggered anymore when pushing a new commit.

So what's the correct syntax for triggering a GitHub Action for a commit but not a tag?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ignore branches or tags, you have to explicitly not ignore the other events you want to trigger on (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore)). So, if you want to ignore all tags, but trigger on all branches:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags-ignore:
      - '**'
    branches:
      - '**'
```

Also, notice the `*` doesn't match the `/` character, so tags or branches with `/` would not be included.